# Which forum software is this site using?

Tags: forum

Can anybody tell me if it's vbulletin/phpbb etc used by this site: seoforums.org .
if it's vbulletin then why is this site: forums.seochat.com so different?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a site you control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source, [seoforums.org](http://www.seoforums.org/) appears to be using vBulletin, as well as [forums.seochat.com](http://forums.seochat.com/). I'm not sure what you mean by "so different"; they could have just applied different CSS styles to each forum.

Comment: Is it very simple to "theme" it and apply beautiful styles in vbulletin?

Comment: Not exactly, nice themes take a while to develop.